# Detect firebug opening and closing

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

Does anybody have a way to detect Firebug opening and closing.

I know you can do the following:

```
if (window.console && window.console.firebug) {
  //Firebug is enabled
}
```

but this only detects the firebug console on page load. What I want to do is on a page where firebug is not open, detect the opening of the firebug console.

I've tried the following, but with no luck

```
setInterval(function(){
  if(window.console && window.console.firebug){
    ...
  else
    ...
}, 1000);
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Matt

Comment: I'm integrating Backfire into a CMS http://blog.quplo.com/2010/08/backfire-save-css-changes-made-in-firebug/ and would like to only display the Save CSS Changes button when firebug is actually open.

Answer (score 2):

Simply.. You cant. The firebug window not just an another couple of div element on your page.

Answer (score 2):

The Firebug window.console object is created just before the first Javascript in the page is executed but only if Firebug is active for the page before the first JS and if the user has the Firebug Console panel enabled.

In other words, from within the page you can only detect if the Console is enabled. But for your purposes that should be enough.

We should delete the console property if a user turns Firebug off for a page.  I don't know if we actually do that.

Comment: Hi John. Your last sentence is probably the most poinient one. Yes, I can check window.console on load, but it doesn't look like window.console is updated (either created when Firebug is opened, or removed when closed) which is what I am trying to detect. So am I right then that there is no way to detect, given a page with firebug closed, when firebug is opened? and vice versa? Other than refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

you can make it as

```
var t = setTimeout("CheckFireBug()",10000);
function CheckFireBug() {
    var t = setTimeout("CheckFireBug()",10000);
    if (window.console && window.console.firebug) {
        //Firebug is enabled
        console.debug('Firebug is enabled.');
    } else {
        //Firebug is not enabled
        console.debug('Firebug is not enabled.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebug overwrites the `console` property of `window`, so you may detect it like so:

```
var _console = window.console;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'console', {
    set: function (x) {
        if (x.exception) { // check if this is actually Firebug, and not the built-in console
            alert('Firebug on');
        }
        _console = x;
    },
    get: function () {
        return _console;
    }
});
```

The problem is that this object remains when Firebug is closed, so you can't detect that. Maybe there's some other way but I can't find it ATM.

**Details:**
It's not possible to access Firebug's execution context from document scripts, so we're limited to waiting for Firebug to access some of `window`'s properties, which does not seem to happen when you close Firebug. Here's some of the events during shutdown, taken with [FBTrace](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/FBTrace):

[image: Firebug stack trace]

I've searched the stacktrace for "leaks" to `window`, but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

console.table() returns "_firebugIgnore" if firebug is running.

```
if( window.console && (console.firebug || 
   console.table && /firebug/i.test(console.table()) ))
{
    alert('Firebug is running');
}else{
    alert('Firebug is not found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to detect Firebug opening/closing you can check window resize/blur events.